# Access Google play account reports through Google API Client PHP Library

Tags: php, google-cloud-storage

- Google Play Developer Account reports are stored on private Google Cloud Storage bucket.
- I want to download these reports programmatically in PHP.
- In this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#export) section-> **Download reports using a client library & service account** provide steps for that.
- But I am not able to achieve it still.
- Also no sample code is available for PHP, as Google API Client PHP Library are still in beta version.

So is it really possible to get access to private Google Cloud Storage bucket in PHP ?

I have already tried out with gsutil tool, but that doesn't exactly satisfy my need.

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

At first you must create an Application Account that you will use for authentication. Go to [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/) >> Settings >> API Access at the bottom of page click "Create Account" (not OAuth). Then set permissions for created account and generate key file in JSON. Should look like this:

```
{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "api-...",
    "private_key_id": "...",
    "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
    "client_email": "...@...iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "...",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/..."
}
```

Next step use generated credentials in your PHP script. Download or require in Composer [Google Cloud Client Library](https://packagist.org/packages/google/cloud).

Use Google Cloud Client Library methods to authorize and download report files:

```
use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;

$client = new StorageClient([
    'scopes' => [StorageClient::READ_ONLY_SCOPE],
    'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents('yourKeyFile.json'), true)
]);
$bucket = $client->bucket('pubsite_prod_rev_*'); //Find your bucket name in Google Developer Console >> Reports

//List all objects in bucket
foreach ($bucket->objects(['prefix' => 'stats/installs/']) as $object) {
    print_r($object->name());
}

//Download some file
$file = $bucket->object('stats/installs/installs_*_overview.csv');
$file->downloadToFile();

//Or print as string
echo $file->downloadAsString();
```

Comment: For the developers of the future: @icoder solution is the correct one. When you create the service account and grant permission to it, you have to wait some hours (24 for me) in order to use your service account for reports download. I wasted one week in creating/delete service accounts but you have just to be patient

Comment: if I understood the provided link (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870#export) correctly, the service account is created in a different google cloud project, and not in the Google Play Android Developer project. 

@Stefano, can you confirm that is what you did? Did you create the service account in another project (via google cloud console), or actually in the API Access area of the Google Play Console?