# How to get Play Console reports' bucket name programmatically?

Tags: google-play, google-play-developer-api

#### Context

The Google Play Console monthly reports are available to download programmatically from Google Cloud Storage, but the only way I have found to get the Storage bucket name is by manually checking inside the Play Console[1][2]. This is a bit to involved to ask from our users.

#### My question

Is it possible to get the bucket name from the Play Console account number and/or package name?

---

[1] https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en#export

[2] https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2015/04/integrate-play-data-into-your-workflow.html

Comment: I know it's too late, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41637857/1330787) answer is helped to me.